# Dynamic pivot inside procedure (SQL Server 2008) no fields on SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a problem with find solution on how to put inside procedure 3 different dynamic pivot query (example below) and use it in SSRS where I can't add datasets, there are no fields. Another important thing is that at the beginning of my procedure I have one parameter "@Data_x" as the date when I am trying to ad datasets there is an info: "Define Query Parameters" and on the list is only "@Data_x" which I can't define "manually".

Here is example of dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @PmtCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query_ppl AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @PmtCols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(number) 
                    from #data
                    group by number
                    order by number
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##ready') is not null drop table ##ready

set @query = 'SELECT ID,' + @PmtCols + ' into ##ready  from 
             (select number, ID, przerwa_pl from #data) as x
            PIVOT 
            (max(przerwa_pl) for number in (' + @PmtCols + ')) as p'
execute(@query) ;
```

I tried to function FMTONLY OFF/ON but still nothing. What can I do, please help?

Comment: You do realise that a matrix in SSRS will do all your pivoting for you, and you don't need to use dynamic SQL at all?

Comment: Yes I do, but in my data it doesn,t work, I'am usin two sources, part with dynamic pivot is only one, when I am trying to put it together it doesn't work. The best way will be put it in one procedure.

Comment: If the number and names of columns varies SSRS will not be able to determine the columns. The query must always return the same column names.

Comment: It isn't the best way because it doesn't work! You can still join your two sets of data before you do the pivot, you will just need to make sure you group by the fields from the second dataset, as well as the relevant fields in the data set you are trying to pivot.

Comment: Ok let say I want to learn other way and I am trying to understand how it works inside stored procedure :) /

Comment: Alan do Yo mean that whena I have a dynamic numbers of colums? Everyday I suppose there will be different number and names. no solution for this?

Comment: As GarethD has stated, the SSRS matrix is the proper solution.

Comment: Thanks guys for help but as I said on the begining because of type of data I need do this in one procedure and I can learn something new. I saw the solution of similar case in other tag, but it doesn't work at my case this is the reason why I am asking about it, I know it is possible to do this in procedure.